# Pass $id from blade to controller method show Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I am a laravel beginner and trying to pass id to controller method show. It does not showing anything after page reloads. I tried some google stuffs. It didnt bring any help. My related code is given below :

admin.blade.php

```
<div class="showOne">
<?php if(isset($users)){
    var_dump($users);
}
?>
```

```
@foreach($inputs as $key => $user)
  <tr>
   <td>{{ ++$key }}</td>
   <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
   <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
   <td>{{ $user->address }}</td>
   <td>{{ $user->phone }}</td>
   <td>
    {{ Form::open(['route' => ['admin.show', $user->id], 'method' => 'get']) }}
    {{ Form::button('Details') }}
    {{ Form::close() }}
   </td>
   <td>
    {{ Form::open(['route' => ['admin.edit', $user->id], 'method' => 'get']) }}
    {{ Form::button('Edit') }}
    {{ Form::close() }}
   </td>
   <td>
    {{ Form::open(['route' => ['admin.delete', $user->id], 'method' => 'get']) }}
    {{ Form::button('Delete') }}
    {{ Form::close() }}
   </td>
 </tr>
@endforeach
```

controller:

```
class AdminController extends \BaseController {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        // get all the inputs
        $inputs = Userdatas::all();

        // load the view and pass the inputs
        return View::make('pages.admin')
            ->with('inputs', $inputs);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $user = Userdatas::find($id);
        var_dump($user);
        die();
        return View::make('pages.admin')
            ->with('users', $user);
    }

}
```

routes:

```
Route::get('admin', [
  'uses' => 'AdminController@index'
]);

Route::get('admin/{id}', [
  'uses' => 'AdminController@show',
  'as' => 'admin.show'
]);
```

Comment: When you click the button, how does the url look like? `admin/1` ?

Comment: No. but i inspected the button, it looks admin/1

Comment: So what's the URL after you click it?

Comment: only my blade name.. http://laravelproject.app/admin

Comment: It's possible that the `$id` is ok and the problem might be with `Userdatas::find();`  what does `var_dump($id)` give you?

Comment: What if you use a link instead? `{{ link_to_route('admin.show', 'Details', $user->id) }}`

Comment: nothing. I used var_dump($id); die(); in controller@show method, that should die and give some value. but not happening anything. In controller@index method Userdatas::all() giving all the data from db

Comment: used:

{{ Form::button(link_to_route('admin.show', 'Details', $user->id)) }}

still no luck

Comment: @WahidSherief No not inside a button. Just as a posted it. It generates a HTML link (`<a/>` tag)

Comment: thanks @lukasgeiter , but no luck still

Answer (score 2):

You could just use a link and let Laravel handle it to the propper action via your routes.

See the example below:

```
// Management
Route::get('management', 'ManagementController@showUser');
Route::get('management/add', 'ManagementController@showAdd');
Route::post('management/add', 'ManagementController@postAdd');
Route::get('management/edit/{id}', 'ManagementController@showEdit');
Route::post('management/edit/{id}', 'ManagementController@postEdit');
Route::get('management/delete/{id}', 'ManagementController@showDelete');
Route::post('management/delete/{id}', 'ManagementController@postDelete');
```

You can then just make links in your tables and style them via css as buttons.

```
@foreach($ManagementAll as $Management)
<tr>
    <td>{{$Management->username}}</td>
    <td>{{$Management->firstname}}</td>
    <td>{{$Management->lastname}}</td>
    <td>{{$Management->email}}</td>
    <td>{{$Management->created_at}}</td>
    <td>{{$Management->updated_at}}</td>
    <td style="padding-top: 3px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
        <a class="btn btn-default btn-circle" href="{{ URL::to('management/edit/' . $Management->id) }}"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
        <a class="btn btn-default btn-circle" href="{{ URL::to('management/delete/' . $Management->id) }}"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Controller Show:

```
public function showEdit($ID)
{
    //Return View With Management User Information
    return View::make('management.edit')
        ->with('User', Management::find($ID));
}
```

Controller Post:

```
public function postEdit($ID)
{
    //Handle Input
    //Validation?
    //Update Record
    //Redirect Back
}
```

See this website for more information about this topic:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-laravel-crud-with-resource-controllers

**Update**

My view folder looks like this:

```
views
  management
    overview.blade.php
    add.blade.php
    edit.blade.php
    delete.blade.php
```

Comment: it is working to some extent but now it showing error that "undefined variable inputs at admin.blade.php". I guess it is coming from controller@index method as I used same blade for these two method. Is it necessary to create blade for every method ?

Comment: I use a blade for every method. Cause my edit and delete page are different from each other. Besides that I also use different variables on each of them. If I would use one blade if have to check first if the variable exist other wise I get errors like you are having now. Can you maybe update your admin.blade.php in your first post?